# How to share a SPARQL query result as a datasource

Tags: sparql, datasource, share, apache-drill

i built a Apache Jena fuseki tdb and create some triples in it.  i create some queries by sparql.  the results of the queries seem like a table  which is like a table in RDBMS.  now i want to operate these results by SQL, or share the results as a data source that is like a table or a view in Apache Drill. Is it possible? if it's possible,  how can I realize this thought.

Comment: the result of a `SELECT` query is basically a collection of bindings, but you can also consider it as a table if you request for a columnar format like CSV (TSV). That said, use one of those as requested resultset format and then you can continue on the CSV file in any tool supporting CSV.

Answer (score 2):

I'll list three possibilities.

1. You can try to use Drill's HTTP storage plugin against the Fuseki API serving JSON or XML formatted responses.
2. With more effort you can write a new TDB or Fuseki storage plugin for Drill.
3. As noted in a comment, you can export your data to a file format already queryable by Drill. It looks like JSON, XML and delimited text are options in this vein.